# Can I adjust the aspect ratio on a Nintendo Switch to display on a 4:3 monitor?

Tags: nintendo-switch, monitor

I have a Nintendo Switch, connected to 4:3 LCD computer monitor (GNR TS702) via a DVI-D input and a cable. The picture displays fine, and fills the whole screen at 1280 x 1024, which I imagine means the Switch is outputting 1080p. However the Switch is sending out a widescreen image, which then looks stretched vertically on my screen.
On a Wii / WiiU, you could change the settings on the device to match the screen ratio:

[image: Wii Widescreen Settings]

However, I cannot find any such setting on the Switch.

Does the switch try to ask the screen what ratio / size it is, or does it just not care and leave the monitor / TV to set itself appropriately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, it doesn't seem so. It seems Nintendo imagined that people would only connect to 16:9 displays and did not add any options in the Switch display settings.

I have been having the same trouble for months. I have my switch hooked up to a 4:3 CRT TV via HDMI to RCA converter. It may be possible to find an adapter that can translate the image to show at a proper aspect.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer, because no-one has posted any other solution to this problem without involving additional hardware! I appreciate the time taken to share your experience.

Answer (score -1):

You will be able to manually adjust screen size by selecting System Settings (from the home menu screen)> TV Settings> Adjust Screen Size.

Sources:

[How to Adjust the TV Settings - Nintendo Support](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22331/%7E/how-to-adjust-the-tv-settings)

[r/NintendoSwitch Subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/90utaz/does_anyone_elses_switch_not_fit_their_tv_i_can/)

Comment: Sadly this does not affect the aspect ratio